# Do not show "X flags remaining" on sites where I'm a moderator

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, moderators

Whenever I open a flag dialog on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com), I see that I have 100 flags remaining. This is simply not true; as a ♦ moderator I have an unlimited number of flags. The simplest solution is probably to hide the element; showing something like "unlimited flags remaining" is a bit overkill.

[image]

Comment: ∞ flags remaining?

Comment: I considered that, but probably only for [math.se] moderators :)

Comment: I see that this counter never decrements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [has been implemented now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363104/allow-us-to-see-the-total-flags-we-have-per-day#comment1211722_363104):

[image]