# Include the daily flag limit in the flag dialog

Tags: feature-request, flags, user-interface

Inspired by [this MSO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420883/8967612), I think it would be a good idea if the flag dialog shows the daily limit alongside the number of remaining flags.

Currently, the message at the bottom right of the flag dialog says:

> You have xx flags left today

I propose that we change it into something like:

> Flags left for today: xx of yy

or any other wording that would include the two pieces of information.

This has two benefits, in my opinion:

1. It allows you to know your current daily flag limit without having to [calculate it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149659/348196) (or check it at the start of the day).
2. It allows you to quickly check how many flags you've already spent today.

Could this info be added to the flag dialog?

Comment: The benefits looks to be too short. At the end of the day and over let say at the end of the month, what are the gains for "flaggers"? is there any gain from a community perspective? Will flaggers be more effective having this feature? What pains does this feature relief? Are flaggers stressed for having to calculate every day their current daily flag limit?

Comment: @Rubén there are questions that you know at first glance that it won't get an answer and will be closed. If I know that I just have a few close votes left, I leave these behind and save them for duplicates, that have well written answers. Besides that, do you have any practical use for any of the flag-summary ? It is a missing value in the statistics, why shouldn't we complete it?

Comment: @Thingamabobs It's a matter of priorities / scarce resources / value. With the details included in the question so far, it looks to that this feature will have a relative low use and a relative very low impact. If this has high value for very small user base the best might be to use a user script.

Comment: @Rubén the number already exists and is probably implemented in a few minutes. The value of any number in the flag-summary should be the same. I really don't know why this minor change of a displayed string should even be thing to argue about. Consistency, consequently is what matters here in my opinion.

Comment: There are 19,658 [feature requests without a status tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+-status-completed+-status-bydesign+-status-declined+-status-norepro+-status-deferred+-status-review+-status-planned+-status-reproduced) There are 11,692 having a score of >+3 .Why this one should be considered before the previously posted and/or those having a higher score?

Comment: you counting closed questions as well and the next few requests include bugs or are bigger changes as including a number. I think it is all said here, cause at this point you don't put reasons against, you just been against it for no rational reason. In the end, nobody will come short if this feature request will maintain a positive score.

Comment: @Rubén of the 11,000 how many have a +5 score? Many of those are closed or not reproducible. How many of the 11k are **easy to fix, reproducible, and score 5+**? This is all three.

Comment: @JamesRisner There are 8 questions, open, without status tag, no older than 2 years, having a +50 score `[feature-request] is:question closed:0 -[status*] votes:50 created:2y..`.  / >70 having +20 score. Just to be clear, my comments are intended to help this post to be a  "food for thought" (to be seriously considered). Anyway, please read this the [recent answer from Catija<staff>](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/382665/289691) to "What posts should be escalated to staff using [[meta-tag:status-review]], and how do I escalate them?"

Comment: @Rubén the content of *What makes a good candidate for escalation?* seems to be relevant. Which point affects this question? Again, it is about something that is probably implemented in a few minutes.

Comment: I don't think that "it just takes few minutes" is enough ... that argument makes me think that this post is  betting for gaining the sympathy of a dev with the required authority / privileges willing to do this on their free time. I guess that that happened in the past, and I'm pretty sure that this could happen at any time. It's opt to you and the OP to keep the post as is. Anyway, thanks for the conversation.

Comment: @Rubén a relevant number might be how many questions and answers exists on all StackExchange sites that are searching for this number, I would include how to calculate it, cause most likely someone would calculate it just to get a result. Right? If you have that number multiply it with 5 minutes and you get the time wasted by folks trying to compensate the lack of this number. The  sum of questions+answers is the same that this lack could have been closed if it would possible for those that refer to the number.

Comment: @Thingamabobs Ruben's comment is just to set (or not) an expectation that the SE's priority is not always the same as the community's needs. Thus, however easy and useful the feature requests are, there's no guarantee that they will be implemented in [6-8 minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/241919).

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. I do understand that and there is no expectation that this will be done tomorrow. I do not feel entitled to demand something what so ever. It's not like people waving signs and won't work anymore till it is done. If you think you don't need, then leave it alone. If you think it will bother you, then go against it. That is what I meant with *In the end, nobody will come short if this feature request will maintain a positive score.*

Comment: some might call this a dup of https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/363104/997587. In fact, I'm quite tempted to dup-vote. But that request was rather poorly received for other reasons.